Nginx reverse proxy behind a OpenVPN Client
I'm trying to set up a Nginx reverse proxy and an OpenVPN client on a Debian machine. Traffic should be routed from the OpenVPN client to the reverse proxy. The purpose of the OpenVPN client is to provide a public IP address. Request made to the public OpenVPN IP (let's call it x.x.x.x) or the associated domain (sentry.mycompany.com) should be routed to my reverse proxy, which should then route the traffic to http://localhost:9000.
I've got both the OpenVPN client and the Nginx server working separately. The problem is that the traffic isn't routed in between.
This is my Nginx config:
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        proxy_buffering on;
        proxy_buffer_size    128k;
        proxy_buffers        4 256k;

        location / {
            proxy_pass       http://localhost:9000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

}

Requests to my local IP (10.10.1.70) works fine, and traffic is successfully redirected to http://localhost:9000.
This is my OpenVPN config:
client
route-nopull
dev tun
proto tcp-client
data-ciphers AES-256-CBC:AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM:CHACHA20-POLY1305
tun-mtu 1400
mssfix 1360
tls-timeout 60
remote super-secret-server-url.net
port 1194
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server
verb 5
mute 10
tls-cert-profile insecure
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
auth-user-pass /.secrets/vpn/credentials.txt
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----



-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>

This configuration is valid, and the connection to the server is successful. I've configured route-nopull since I don't want OpenVPN to mess with my routes. Leaving route-nopull out makes my server inaccessible from the local network (10.10.1.70) and also does not make the server accessible from the OpenVPN public IP. I want to be able to access the machine from the local network as well.
Connecting to the OpenVPN sever sets up a new network interface:
11: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1400 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 192.168.90.174/24 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8bd:d4a6:8d40:8b46/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

The assigned IP is correct. My VPN provider does NAT port forward from the external IP x.x.x.x to the "local" OpenVPN IP (192.168.90.174).
To summarize, I want to configure it as follows:

Request to x.x.x.x or sentry.mycompany.com
My VPN service provider forwards traffic to 192.168.90.174
My machine is getting the traffic on tun0
The traffic from tun0 should be routed to my Nginx reverse proxy
The Nginx proxy should forward traffic on port 80 to http://localhost:9000
Request via my local network (10.10.1.70) should also be possible (SSH, etc.).

How can I accomplish this?

You need to tunnel all your internet facing traffic via OpenVPN tunnel, and then the OpenVPN server needs to masquerade the traffic, so that the source IP address is OpenVPN server's IP address.
If you want to avoid sending all traffic via the OpenVPN tunnel, that is possible. It requires setting IPTables rules to mark traffic from nginx with packet mark, and then adding a secondary routing table that is used for that traffic mark. I only know generic principle, I cannot give detailed instructions how to do it.
To explain why, let's first assume:
OpenVPN server has IP address 192.0.2.1
Your local network external IP address is 198.51.100.1
Your OpenVPN client end IP address is 192.168.90.174
Then, let's consider a request that comes into your server.
Client from 203.0.113.1 sends a request to OpenVPN server 192.0.2.1. The OpenVPN server changes destination IP address to 192.168.90.174.
Now, your web server receives the request from IP 203.0.113.1, and sends response back to it.
If the response packet is not forwarded via OpenVPN tunnel, it will be masqueraded by your home router. Therefore the response packet for 203.0.113.1 will come from 198.51.100.1.
Therefore when client gets the response packet, it drops it because it doesn't come from expected location.
